# SurfaceView transparente em cima da Toolbar

Tags: android

Estou desenhando um gráfico, e para isso estou usando uma Classe que estende de `SurfaceView`.

A tela onde será desenhado, possui uma imagem de fundo. 
Então, para que o `SurfaceView` fique transparente, fiz o seguinte:

```
 setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 setZOrderOnTop(true);
 surfaceHolder = getHolder();
 surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Funcionou! a área do `SurfaceView` ficou transparente, mas quando dou o scroll na tela, o `SurfaceView` fica por cima da `Toolbar`.

Acredito que se deva pela seguinte linha:

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Mas se removo, ou seto como `false` o fundo fica preto!

Como posso deixar um `SurfaceView` transparente e manter o `Z` abaixo do `Toolbar`?

Comment: Você viu essa resposta? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7061396/2570426